# How to move a python3/gtk3 application to new 'pantheon-filechooser-module'?

Tags: pantheon-files, programming, python

Thank you for your great work.

I have some problems since elementary OS 0.3.1 makes `pantheon-filechooser-module` as the default one. I suppose there is maybe a GObject/Gtk/pixman issue because I can reproduce it with this [python script](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html#id2).

```
$ python3 the_script.py
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

Then, either click on "Choose File" or "Choose Folder":

```
(the_script.py:4167): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_add: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
```

and more annoying it breaks [Gramps 4.2.0](https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps/releases/download/gramps-4.2.0/python3-gramps_4.2.0_all.deb) where
Gtk3 FileChooserDialog is called on many modules. (`git`, `grep`, etc.)

The "visual" issue is that without widget action buttons (OK, Cancel)
into the File Chooser Dialog or any header bar, we cannot close the 
dialog and we need to kill the application. Really annoying into Gramps,
where I cannot import file, select a backup folder, set preferred folder,
import any media object, etc ...

I should be able to test and patch gramps but I have no idea how
to properly migrate or fix current python3 modules 
calling Gtk3 FileChooserDialog under recent pantheon shell 
(elementary OS 0.3.1).

Any clue or tips will be welcome.

regards,

Comment: A little bit strange, but today I am now able to get the action buttons!

Comment: ... but at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Calling Gtk.FileChooserButton() from
"_/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/tweaks/theme.py_" sounds good into "_ubuntu-tweak_", by returning the expected dialog with widget (button) actions at the top of the window! :-)

Unfortunately, to use it into the above python sample script:
e.g,
        `button3 = Gtk.FileChooserButton()
        button3.connect('file-set', self.on_file_clicked)
        box.add(button3)`

will still failed. :-(

Related to parent window?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Comment: " it appears to be abandoned" ? you need more patience !